# Bind data using multiply NSArrayControllers and NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

#### Question

How to display data in **Subgroup** based on row selection in **Group** ?

#### Question naming

- `NSTableView` with name **Group**
- `NSTableView` with name **Subgroup**
- **Group** `NSArrayController` with name **Groups**
- **Subgroup** `NSArrayController` with name **Subgroups**

#### Additional data

- Relationship between **Group** and **Subgroup** in `Data Model` is set as `to-many`
  [image: Core Data Model]
- **Groups** is used as controller for **Group** table view
- **Subgroups** is used as controller for **Subgroup** table view

[image: Table View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Anwser is:

Set `Controller Content` > `Content Set` in `Bindings Inspector` to `Model Key Path` to `relationship` name.

[image: Solution]